# How to do/filter a SQL JOIN if the primary key has appended text on it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have “values” that have text appended to the numeric value. OR12345 for instance.

We have multiple tables and in the primary table we have values such as OR12345, OR12346, OR12347 etc

Secondary tables are just the INTEGER part of the ID such as 12345, 12346, and 12347

I've tried a basic LEFT JOIN but it only picks up one tables values. I've considered a LIKE wildcard value but that did not seem viable or at least I did not know the syntax to achieve that method and create a dynamic selection variable.

My basic query is such:

```
SELECT 
    J.CurJLId, SC.OrderId, SC.ShippingMethodId, SC.SendProgressEmails 
FROM 
    [PD_Jobs] J
LEFT JOIN 
    [SM_ShopCart] SC ON SC.OrderId = J.InvoiceId
WHERE 
    J.CurJLId > 'JL30' 
    AND SC.SendProgressEmails = 1
```

Table `[SM_ShopCart]`:

| OrderId | SendProgressEmails |
| --- | --- |
| OR189231 | 1 |
| OR192583 | 0 |
| OR196583 | 1 |
| OR198100 | 1 |
| OR201758 | 0 |
| OR203259 | 0 |
| OR204663 | 1 |
| OR205053 | 1 |
| OR206126 | 0 |
| OR212160 | 1 |

Table `[PD_Jobs]`:

| InvoiceId | CurJLId |
| --- | --- |
| 189231 | JL14 |
| 192583 | JL24 |
| 196583 | JL30 |
| 198100 | JL24 |
| 201758 | JL34 |
| 203259 | JL38 |
| 204663 | JL24 |
| 205053 | JL54 |
| 206126 | JL24 |
| 212160 | JL24 |

Should I be creating an embedded `SELECT` and then screen that to remove the 'OR'?

This is a very complicated query for my skill level. If I can get some help in the logic and proper structure it would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the table PD_Jobs have a JobId column too? or did you mean InvoiceId?

Comment: Yes, it does... Though those values have dashes at the end. I'll update my example query to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is it always "OR" that's prefixed? I would assume you would have stated were that not the case?

Comment: Correct, it's always 'OR" for Order

Comment: This design is broken. If InvoiceId really is a foreign key to the OrderId, it should be identical, not similar. As-is there can't actually be a foreign key constraint, joins become messy, the benefits of indexes can become lost. In short, is fixing your design an option?

Comment: @MatBailie no, it's an old working complex database. I understand your point but the normalization is present, it just looks broken from this perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something similar to this works?

```
SELECT J.CurJLId, SC.OrderId, SC.ShippingMethodId, SC.SendProgressEmails 
FROM [PD_Jobs] J
LEFT JOIN [SM_ShopCart] SC  ON SC.OrderId = 'OR' + CAST(J.InvoiceId as VARCHAR)  
WHERE J.CurJLId > 'JL30' AND SC.SendProgressEmails = 1
```

Comment: ... or substring and cast to int

Comment: That works well to pull results where SC.SendProgressEmails = 1
Would the same logic allow filtering the J.CurJLId as greater than 'JL30' ?
In other words strip the 'JL' part and focus on the INT as Greater Than ('>')?

Comment: Yeah, you could do something like CAST(REPLACE(J.CurJLId, 'JL', '') AS INT) > 30

Comment: Beware that casting to varchar [should always specify a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) and casting CurJLId is also unsargable for an index seek.

Comment: The casting is based on an assumption - OP do you see and understand that? Surely you have older invoices that do not have 6 digit invoice IDs - try using those for your testing.

Answer (score 4):

When joining tables the data types of the joined columns should match.

Joining a varchar column with an int column will require one type to be cast to the other, which will mean an index *seek* will not be possible as this is an *unsargable* operation; you are *forcing* SQL Server to evaluate every row before it knows whether the casted value can be joined.

To join your tables you can do either of the following:

```
SELECT J.CurJLId, SC.OrderId, SC.SendProgressEmails 
FROM  PD_Jobs J
LEFT JOIN SM_ShopCart SC ON Stuff(SC.OrderId,1,2,'') = J.InvoiceId
WHERE J.CurJLId > 'JL30' and SC.SendProgressEmails = 1

SELECT J.CurJLId, SC.OrderId, SC.SendProgressEmails 
FROM  PD_Jobs J
LEFT JOIN SM_ShopCart SC ON SC.OrderId = Concat('OR',J.InvoiceId)
WHERE J.CurJLId > 'JL30' and SC.SendProgressEmails = 1
```

However, if performance matters at all you would be better off adding a persisted indexed computed column to the `SM_ShopCart` table to permanently fix the data type as int which will allow SQL Server to efficiently join your tables.

```
alter table SM_ShopCart add InvoiceId as Cast(Stuff(OrderId,1,2,'') as int) persisted
create index IX_InvoiceId on SM_ShopCart(InvoiceId) /* include (covering columns)*/
```

Then your query can just join the two tables with no data type conversion

```
SELECT J.CurJLId, SC.OrderId, SC.SendProgressEmails 
FROM  PD_Jobs J
LEFT JOIN SM_ShopCart SC ON SC.InvoiceId = J.InvoiceId
WHERE J.CurJLId > 'JL30' and SC.SendProgressEmails = 1
```

Note that in addition, your criteria `J.CurJLId > 'JL30'` is not going to work as you expect:

```
if 'JL30' > 'JL100' print 'oops'
```

Comment: Includes the OP's mistake of `j LEFT JOIN sc WHERE sc.x = 1`

Comment: Ah yes good spot I noticed that and forgot to mention it, effectively an inner join.